# Yii2 как узнать в миграции есть ли такой внешний ключ?

Tags: yii2

При создании миграции хочу убедиться что такого внешнего ключа не существует

```
$this->createForeignKey(
            self::TABLE_NAME,
            self::COLUMN,
            self::FOREIGN_TABLE_NAME,
            'id',
            'SET NULL',
            'CASCADE'
        );
```

Comment: Откуда он может появиться?

Comment: в случае его ручного добавления/ошибки при добавлении/удалении

Comment: Нужно ли вам рассматривать ручное добавление при использовании миграций? Нужно ли вам делать такую миграцию, которая применится только наполовину?

Comment: сейчас такая проблема - на боевой базе нет фк, в дев есть. как это произошло непонятно. мне нужно одинаковое поведение и на проде и на деве. т.е. нужно на деве проверить есть ли уже фк

Comment: Чтобы таких ситуаций не возникало, лучше делать по методу Макарова: называть индексы как `idx-table_name-column`, внешние ключи как `fk-table_name-column`, или даже `fk-table_name-column-ref_table-ref_columnn`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function safeUp()
{
    Yii::$app->db->schema->refreshTableSchema(self::TABLE_NAME);
    $tableSchema = Yii::$app->db->schema->getTableSchema(self::TABLE_NAME, true);
    if (!in_array(
        self::COLUMN,
        array_keys($tableSchema->foreignKeys)
    )) {
        $this->createForeignKey(
            self::TABLE_NAME,
            self::COLUMN,
            self::FOREIGN_TABLE_NAME,
            'id',
            'SET NULL',
            'CASCADE'
        );
    }
}
```